# Filling Rows evenly with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to displays rows of content in an app that uses Bootstrap 3. Each row will container the row number and a variable number of blocks. Basically, it will looks something like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| 1  | Block 1  || Block 2  |
+---------------------------+
| 2  | #1 || #2 || #3 || #4 |
+---------------------------+
| 3  |    One Large Block   |
+---------------------------+
| 4  |  1/3 ||  2/3 ||  3/3 |
+---------------------------+
```

I might have 100 rows. For that reason, the width of the first column (the one with the row number) will always be 100px. However, I want the remaining available space to be filled with my blocks evenly. Currently, I have the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .record {
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 24px;
    background-color: silver;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }

  .item {
            display: inline-block;
            color:white;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            font-size: 80%;
        }
</style>

<div class="record">
  <span class="badge" style="width:100px;">04</span>
  <a class="item" data-html="true" data-content="Item 1">1/3</a>
  <a class="item" data-html="true" data-content="Item 2">2/3</a>
  <a class="item" data-html="true" data-content="Item 3">3/3</a>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is, the items are all left-aligned. The do not evenly fill the remaining space in the row beside "04". I cannot set a value of "width:33%" because each record will have a variable number of items.

How do I fill the remaining space and evenly distribute it with a variable number of items with CSS/Bootstrap?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox to solve this one? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is, Divide the Viewport into two parts. if you are using 12 Grid System

col-md-1  ||  Col-md-11

Now again divide col-md-11 into 12 equal parts, and fill the row with desired values depending upon the content, the brackets represents col-md-11 has been again divided into . by that way you need not hard code the values.

```
    col-md-1 || col-md-11 ( col-md-6 , col-md-6)
    col-md-1 || col-md-11 ( col-md-4 , col-md-4, col-md-4)
    col-md-1 || col-md-11 ( col-md-3 , col-md-3, col-md-3, col-md-4)
    col-md-1 || col-md-11 ( col-md-2 , col-md-2, col-md-2, col-md-6)
```

I hope this would solve your problem.